# how to make symfony2 writes log in prod mode?

Tags: symfony, xdebug

I would like to make symfony writes in the file app/logs in prod mode.
Notice that symfony writes logs in dev mode.

Is there any idea?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

For example:

```
 monolog:
     handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
```

Hope it's helpful

Best regard